# Trouble publishing my app to appStore:  entitlements, bundleID, plist...?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I am getting a number of errors with the ApplicationLoader. But it looks like I have done things wrong in XCode4.2.1 and possible with certificates or profiles.  Last time I submitted an App was with Xcode3.2.6. Not sure what to do here with Xcode4.2.1?  thanks

### [image]

After working with things a bit I have gotten to this point:

-the referencing not sure of

-code signing, I thought the process of the certs/downloading/uploading to apples sight took care of this.

[image]

---

And now down to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining problems are easy to solve.

**First the Icon:**

Make sure you have named your icons as

- icon.png
- icon@2x.png

Then on the *appname*-Info.plist there should be a key called

"Icon Files (iOS 5)"

with a subkey

"Primary Icon"

with a subkey

"Icon files"

and 2 subkeys

"Item 0" and "Item 1"

Item 0 value should be icon.png and item 1 should be icon@2x.png

**For your second problem:**

You have to specify what code signing profile you want to use.

For this select your app on the item inspector and under Targets select your app again.

Then under build settings, select All and combined.

Here just scroll down to "Code Signing"

The code signing identity MUST have the RELEASE value to the same profile that has been registered on the iTunes connect (the certificate that you got which has the rights to publish etc etc)

just click on the value and you should see many provisioning profiles. If the Provisioning profile has been installed correctly (the one that can sign for release) it should also appear there, just select it.

Repeat the process for the Project configuration (Under Project -> AppName).

**Edit:**

if you have Entitlements defined:

> If you are defining a custom Code Signing Entitlements file within
>   your Target > Build Settings, you might try removing that
>   configuration entirely and rebuilding/resubmitting. More often than
>   not, Code Signing Entitlements are defined unnecessarily. You only
>   need to specify a custom Code Signing Entitlements file if your
>   application is utilizing custom keychain access sharing or iCloud.
>   Otherwise, remove the Code Signing Entitlements configuration from all
>   build configurations on your Xcode project's Target > Build Settings,
>   the rebuild and reattempt your submission/validation.

Regarding the code signing issue:

Try following this apple guide, it explains everything very detailed

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Especially the **How do I resolve the error: Application failed codesign verification?** Section.

Comment: Thanks for assisting.  On the iOS Provisioning Portal it lists the same Distribution Provisioning Profile that I found when selecting it for the Code Signing Identity for Release.  But I still get that error:  The application failed codesign verification.

Comment: Make sure that they are set on both the "release" and the "any iOS SDK" with the correct signing identity. Or try another provisioning profile that appears from the list.

Comment: Tried all combination for codesign verification... error is consistent.  That same error refers to possible iPhone Distribution Certificate issue... For the initial setup I went through all that and I down loaded and upload the info for cert, how/what can I verify things there?  thx

Comment: When you created the distribution certificate did you make sure that the distribution Method is Appstore?

Comment: Oh forgot to mention, you have to set the correct code sign profile for both the Project and the Target, both are under Build Settings

Comment: Had that setup as well... the other part to codesign is the Entitlements.  I had them set in the TARGETS:Summary and made reference to them in the Code Signing Entitlements.  Not sure if I needed, but I remembered working with Entitlements in Xcode3.2.6.